# Bounty Questions - Should Gold Badge or High Reps users have the ability to close?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I came across a bounty question once, in which I deemed it to have been a duplicate( [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695394/mimic-the-css-background-cover-img-property-in-html) if anyone's looking) - however, my flag was declined due to 'no evidence'. I'm not here to argue that.
[image]

---

But with moderators always being so busy, I thought 'well, high rep users could be trusted, could they not decide if the question is on topic or not'. Esp Gold badge users, of whom clearly have skill in those tags to decide if a question is on topic or not.

However, I have once again come across a bounty question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335236/internet-explorer-preserve-3d-fix).

In which would seem nearly identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround) that was posted back in 2012, but I'm reluctant to flag since my previous experience is somewhat holding me back, since I feel as sure now as i did then that it is indeed, off topic (via dupe).

Would it be a possibility to consider allowing gold badge users this kind of ability - allowing them to close (say, after three gold users flag a bounty) to close it?

Comment: I don't see where a bounty was ever placed or awarded on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28695394/1288), which might be why your flag was declined.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was looking at a mod/admin timeline and didn't see it. It is there, now that I know what timestamps to look for. The flag was processed after the bounty ended, which *might* be the reason it was declined if the other mod also didn't see the bounty.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That's no problem. But as I did say, I wasn't disputing that flag :P

Comment: It's a "feature" that questions can't be closed while there's an open bounty on them, and it's been discussed before. While I would love to see that feature gone, it might be more trouble than it's worth to partially implement.

Comment: See also [Using Bitwise operator to divide by zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170130/using-bitwise-operator-to-divide-by-0-simulation-of-division-by-0).  Downvoted to -7.  Would have been closed/deleted, except for bounty +100, which was awarded.

Comment: @Paul OP spends 100+ rep to get an answer, got comprehensive answers, and we can close it now. As far as I can see, no problem.

Answer (score 13):

I would say no, gold badge users and high rep users should not have the ability to close a question with a bounty on it.

If that were to happen, people would complain they lost (potentially a lot to some people) reputation, unless it gets refunded. Refunding a bounty is not something that is commonly done - I don't want to start opening a floodgate where bounty refunds start becoming common place or we start asking for more ways to refund a bounty. This could also impact people that spent a lot of time working on an answer for a question with a bounty. I would be a little annoyed if I sunk a few hours into an answer only to have the bounty cancelled and refunded.

Comment: however, on the flip side why would you answer an off topic question in the first place?

Comment: @jbutler483 "off topic" is always up for interpretation to some degree (hence why we *vote* to close off topic questions). I might think something is on topic, and answer it for bounty, but it gets closed anyway. If the question is a duplicate, then there isn't anything immediately wrong with the question, and it looks perfectly valid.

Comment: @vcsjones: I would like to remain impartial here (as i said, it was a consideration only). However, Gold badge users *would* know if its topicality is right. If there is some 'disputed' claim, then maybe go to mods to decide?

Comment: I have a gold badge in [c#], and frankly I look at a lot of C# questions and cannot say, with certainly, if all 782,228 of them is topically correct. Sure, we can have "reopen" votes, but that adds even more complexity. Does the bounty get added back automatically if it got refunded? If it didn't get refunded, does that person have to spend the bounty *again*? The only way I could see this even remotely working is with refunds, and I don't want those either for the reasons I already outlined.

Comment: Hence why this question was posted: to consider, not request (as someone readded the [tag:feature-request] tag, i've left it be). But what I was saying though, was an idea to possibly remove some of the pressure of the mods. After all, you at least know if *some* of those 782k questions are off topic or not. in fact, you may have read more of them than the mods have (since they don't just admin one specific tag, they have to monitor all 9,250,334). So it would be more likely for someone who's hanging around the c# tag to see an off topic question there than a mod there. That's my point.

Comment: SE just doesn't trust hi-rep users that much.  Even the gold dup hammer has no teeth, the question can instantly be reopened again.   It is just much more effective to DV it so it can be auto-deleted.

Comment: @HansPassant: Does the hammer not require votes from rep'd users to do such?

Answer (score 5):

Only if the bounty reputation is refunded, and I'm tempted to just argue 'no'.

I know, it's troublesome to see off-topic stuff and have to leave it. There is one in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) that I keep seeing myself.

If the question asks how to freebase or fix a car you could flag it, but if it's about programming and generally OK, just let it be. It's their reputation and this doesn't happen very often. If we close questions where users spent reputation to try to get answers, it's more likely to cause outcry because it's unfair.

If you really want to, you can still vote it down.

Comment: "doesn't happen very often". I see closeworthy questions with bounties on them every... single... day.

Comment: @Louis But compare this to the number of questions we close without a bounty, it's actually small.

Answer (score 3):

I support the general idea. Closeworthy questions should be closed, even when they're bountied.

I've seen a few closeworthy bountied question in my day, and each time, I remember thinking it was silly that the only way to get it closed as it should was to have a moderator get manually involved.

Some kind of "high-threshold" close-voting process (high rep, or gold badge, or...) would be a reasonable compromise between the current manual process, which is too manual, and the close process for garden-variety questions, which does not provide enough protection.

Bounty refunding is a secondary issue. Refund? No refund? Only refund if no answer yet? Whatever, they all work for me.